Remove All Databases From Azure Analysis Server With PowerShell
Ok I have this script, it should be straightforward:
# Load the Microsoft.AnalysisServices assembly from the NuGet package
$amoPath = (Join-Path (Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE ".nuget\packages\microsoft.analysisservices.tabular") "13.0.2150.3\lib\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.dll")
Add-Type -Path $amoPath

$amoPath = (Join-Path (Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE ".nuget\packages\microsoft.analysisservices.tabular") "13.0.2150.3\lib\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.dll")
Add-Type -Path $amoPath

# Connect to the AAS instance
$connectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP;DataSource=asazure://eastus.asazure.windows.net/myservernamehere;User ID=BlahBlah;Password=SuperSecretPassword;Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate;"

$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
$server.Connect($connectionString)

# Delete all databases in the server
foreach ($database in $server.Databases) {
    Write-Host "Deleting database: $($database.Name)"
    $database.Drop()
}

# Disconnect from the server
$server.Disconnect()

And of course it isn't:

Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "The connection
string is not valid."
$server.Connect($connectionString)
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectionException

The funny part is I can do the same thing in C# with the same connection string, without any issues...
using (Server server = new Server())
{
    server.Connect(serverConnectionString);

    // Collect databases to drop in a separate list
    List<Database> databasesToDrop = new List<Database>();

    foreach (Database element in server.Databases)
    {
        databasesToDrop.Add(element);
    }

    databasesToDrop.AsParallel().ForAll(element =>
    {
        element.Drop();
    });
}

I am at a lose for what the issue is, what is wrong with the connection string?
I've tried messing around with different authentication methods, same issue really, works in c#, doesn't work in powershell...

Are both the C# and PS using the same NuGet packages at the same versions?

@IanKemp Yes, I've tried a few different versions, same error


Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "The connection string is not valid." $server.Connect($connectionString) CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectionException

The above error is causing due to the incorrect connection string please check the credentials are correct or not.
To connect to the SQL Server Analysis Service. The SQL Server Analysis Service can be accessed by using the Analysis Management Objects. To use AMO. Try following code to load the assembly and creates and initializes an instance of the SQL Server Analysis Service:
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")  
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular");  
  
$SSASServer = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
$SSASServer = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server;

Also refer these SO answers to connect Azure SQL Analysis Service:
How to connect to Azure Analysis Service Server using AAD App Registration in PowerShell
How to list the databases/models under Azure Analysis Services using Powershell?

The credentials are the same between the C# and PowerShell version, the credentials are correct... The method you suggest results in "Cannot find type [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded." which if you look into it further results in a bit of a rabbit hole of loading libraries through powershell, I never got anywhere with that approach which resulted in me trying to load that libraries by hand.
